# Afnetworking post array

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking-2

Im trying to post with an array as the post instead of a dictionary. However i get an error:

```
Incompatible pointer types sending NSMutableArray to parameter of type NSDictionary
```

Here is the code

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSMutableArray *parameters = @[@"foo", @"bar"];
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

How can I post JUST the arrays contents?

#### Update:

This code works, but I would prefer to get the answer below working as its cleaner and af handles the serialization. Im guessing the request body is different, but how do i see what the body is?

```
  NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                         error:&error];
    NSString *body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/resources.json"]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData  timeoutInterval:10];
    
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        
        NSLog(@"JSON responseObject: %@ ",responseObject);
        
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        
    }];
    [op start];
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you are wanting this to work. `foo` & `bar` need to be assigned to a variable

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want `foo` and `bar` to be your parameters without any values? if so you will want to do something like this

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSMutableArray *parameters = @[@"foo", @"bar"];
NSDictionary *params = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[[NSNull null], [NSNull null]] forKeys:parameters];
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

**EDIT**
Try adding

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Comment: This is close. I can get the request to complete successfully. But the body is blank. I believe this is because the request body is different than what it should be. I updated my question with a less elegant solution. Can you tell me how to view the request body?

Comment: I had to add the requestserializer to get it to work initially. I did set the response but had done so incorrectly (had set it to afhttpresponse), even with correcting that ` NSLog(@"%@",operation.responseString);` still comes back with an empty array. When its truly successful its a populated array.